# Strange Results for String comparison in PHP

Tags: php, string, string-comparison, php-5.3

We ran into an issue today that I am surprised I had not encountered before. It was  related to string comparison:

```
echo ("9400110897799014514025" == "9400110897799014514018" ? "match" : "not");
echo ("94001108" == "94001107" ? "match" : "not");
```

Neither of the 2 sets matches, yet the first one reports a "match" incorrectly, while the second properly declares it "not" a match. We resolved the issue by using  '===' in place of '==' but I'd really like to understand what is going on here.

Add: It's PHP 5.3

Comment: PHP will automatically cast strings that look like numbers into floats and compare them. If the number is too large for your system, you can get an equality. Using === or strcmp avoids the implicit cast to float.

Comment: Your script returns `notnot`. Am I missing something? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/52fdfde3162fcd28ec3527e9b1276a67f5b1031a

Comment: @waterloomatt It returns notnot on my 64 bit system, but matchnot on my 32 bit system.

Comment: @kainaw: which php version does your 32 bit system run?

Comment: @Stratadox Normally 7. I dropped to 5.3 for this test on both the 32 and 64 bit systems to verify that it is an error resulting from the implicit cast to float. The 32 bit system loses accuracy with the large numbers and considers them equal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried running your code, but I got `notnot` in the first few attempts. Only after lowering the php version to 5.4.3 or below, I got `matchnot`.

It appears you're running on an outdated version of php, and encountered [this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54547). It has been solved since php5.4.4.

The best thing to do is probably to upgrade your php version (although strict comparison isn't a bad thing either way)

**Edit**: According to the comments on the original answer, it looks like the problem persists in later versions as well, but only on 32bit systems.

The problem itself comes from the fact that php is extremely loose with comparisons, converting strings that look like numbers to numbers before comparison. This leads to php considering "1e3" as equal to "1000", for example.

Comment: You could also demonstrate this with the help of https://3v4l.org/2SVAN